# Get total of all orders cost of a specific user programmatically

Tags: commerce

I want to get total cost of all the order placed by an user programmatically in Drupal 8.  I used below code to get total orders count, same way need to get total cost.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQueryAggregate('commerce_order')
  ->condition('uid', $user_id)
  ->condition('state', 'completed')
  ->groupBy('uid')
  ->aggregate('order_id', 'COUNT')
  ->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it will be work or something like this...

```
$user_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
$orders = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
->getStorage('commerce_order')
->loadByProperties(['uid' => $user_id]); 

$orderPrice = [];
foreach($orders as $key => $value) {
   $orderPrice[] = $value->get('total_price')->getValue()['0']['number'];
}
$total = array_sum($orderPrice);
kint($total);
```

Comment: I think this will not work because unit price is order item level, but what we need is total order price.  Also looping through order will have performance issue when there are more  order for a user,

Comment: @Viswa I've edited my answer, is it work for me but... don't know if is it the best practice ;)

Comment: Yes that worked for 1000+ orders without any performance issue.  Also we shall fine tune the code little bit like instead of $value->get('total_price')->getValue()['0']['number'] we can use $value->getTotalPrice()->getNumber().   Also working on entityQueryAggregate to achieve this without looping,  if time permits you can also try.